# How do I show a collection product count in a dropdown menu in Shopify?

Tags: collections, shopify

How to do Shopify Drop-Down Menu: Show collection product count?
I am working on a Shopify Store here and need to display the product count for each collection in the drop-down sub-menu and somehow I can not figure it out. The documentation is a little bit light on this issue. I need the product count to be shown only in the sub-menus.

Comment: Would you please provide your Liquid source code, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:
In your header file

**Step 1:**

After:

`{% for childlink in link.links %}`

ADD these two lines:

```
{% assign collection_handle = childlink.url | split: "collections/" | last %}
{%- assign current_collection = collections[collection_handle] -%}
```

**Step 2:**

After

`{{ childlink.title | escape }}`

ADD

`<span>{{ current_collection.all_products_count }}</span>`

**Note: But keep in mind all links of the menu should be assigned to collections**

Comment: Collection object can be retrieved directly from link object in a linklist.

Comment: how can use the above code or where because it's not working in this nav code, please help to do that  https://imgur.com/a/mBdH2nU

Comment: Sure. If possible can you tell me what theme you are using @AmitKumar?

Comment: @AmitKumar I have updated the answer for you try it now.